# Not able to see the complete equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to write an equation using this LaTeX code

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{n_d}{m_d}.\psi\left(x+1,y\right)+\frac{n_d}{m_d}.\psi\left(x-1,y\right)-2.\left(\frac{n_d}{m_d}+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\right).\psi\left(x,y\right)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}.\psi\left(x,y+1\right)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}.\psi\left(x,y-1\right)=m_d*n_d*\frac{q}{\epsilon}\left(n-p-C\right)
\end{equation}
```

but when I compile it I can only see a part of the equation in the generated pdf.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This equation is just too long. You have to put it on two ore more lines.

Comment: Also note that you can use `\cdot` for a multiplication dot.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is too long to fit in one line. You could use the `split` environment, with the `amsmath` package, to break it in two or more lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{n_d}{m_d}\cdot\psi\left(x+1,y\right)+\frac{n_d}{m_d}\cdot\psi\left(x-1,y\right)-2\cdot\left(\frac{n_d}{m_d}+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\right)\cdot\psi\left(x,y\right) \\
+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\cdot\psi\left(x,y+1\right)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\cdot\psi\left(x,y-1\right)=m_dn_d\frac{q}{\epsilon}\left(n-p-C\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As @Grimler pointed out, I replaced all the dots with `\cdot`.

Comment: @Grimler and Marco: The period is not wrong but just another style. You do not see that very often these days, but it still exists. Just for info.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks for the info, I've never seen it.

Comment: Wiki says it is French or Bulgarian style. Maybe not as obsolescent as I thought. (but personally, I do not like it...)

Answer (score 1):

If an equation is too long to fit on a single line, you need to employ an alternative environment that allows for line breaks. The `multline` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) would seem to be well suited for your equation.

I would also replace all instances of `.` and `*` (dots and stars) with simple thinspaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "multline"  environment

\begin{document}

\noindent
before: \texttt{equation} environment
\begin{equation}
\frac{n_d}{m_d}.\psi\left(x+1,y\right)+\frac{n_d}{m_d}. \psi\left(x-1,y\right)-2. \left(\frac{n_d}{m_d}+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\right). \psi\left(x,y\right)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}. \psi\left(x,y+1\right)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}. \psi\left(x,y-1\right)=m_d*n_d*\frac{q}{\epsilon}\left(n-p-C\right)
\end{equation}

\bigskip\noindent
after: \texttt{multline} environment, no ``.'' or ``$*$'', no \verb+\left+ or \verb+\right+ directives
\begin{multline}
\frac{n_d}{m_d}\, \psi(x+1,y)+\frac{n_d}{m_d}\, \psi(x-1,y)
-2\, \Bigl(\frac{n_d}{m_d}+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\Bigr)\, \psi(x,y)\\
+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\, \psi(x,y+1)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\, \psi(x,y-1)
=m_d\, n_d\, \frac{q}{\epsilon}(n-p-C)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions. I used the `geometry` package, to have more sensible margins, and  a `split` environment. In the second suggestion, I grouped terms in the l.h.s. In both I removed the useless dots, and  all `\left … \right` pairs, replacing only the middle one with a pait `\biggl … \biggr` (the smaller size `\Bigl … \Bigr` might be OK too):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \frac{n_d}{m_d} \psi(x+1,y) & +\frac{n_d}{m_d}.\psi(x-1,y)-2 \biggl(\frac{n_d}{m_d}+ \frac{m_d}{n_d}\biggr) \psi(x,yt) + \frac{m_d}{n_d}\psi(x,y+1)+\frac{m_d}{n_d}\psi(x,y-1) \\ & =m_d*n_d*\frac{q}{\epsilon}(n-p-C)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \frac{n_d}{m_d}\bigl((\psi(x+1,y) + \psi(x-1,y)\bigr) & -2 \biggl(\frac{n_d}{m_d}+ \frac{m_d}{n_d}\biggr) \psi(x,yt) + \frac{m_d}{n_d}\bigl(\psi(x,y+1)+\psi(x,y-1)\bigr) \\ & =m_d*n_d*\frac{q}{\epsilon}(n-p-C)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]